# How to display item at particular index and then after every fifth element in Angular 2+

Tags: angular

I have an array of channels. I am using *ngFor for looping the array of channels.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let channel of channelList; let i = index">

    <!-- Display the below code at index 3 and then after every fifth item -->
    <ng-container *ngIf="i==3">
        <div class="slide pa1" >
            <a class="link bg-center relative" >
                <div class="c-ban relative" style="height: 168px !important;">
                    <app-google-ads></app-google-ads>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </ng-container>

</ng-container>
```

Here I have displayed the content at index 3. But how can I display the content after evert fifth element?

For instance, the item is displayed at index 3, then I want to display content at index 8 and then at index 13 ... (after every fifth element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following. Working out the remainder when you divide by 5 and then - 3 to get the desired offset.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(i % 5) - 3 == 0">
    <div class="slide pa1" >
        <a class="link bg-center relative" >
            <div class="c-ban relative" style="height: 168px !important;">
                <app-google-ads></app-google-ads>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```